# Probability two subsets have the same sum

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Fix $\ell$ and $n$. Let $S_{\ell}$ be a uniformly random chosen subset of size $\ell$ of the set of integers $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  I would like to know the probability that there exist two subsets $A \subset S$ and $B \subset S$ with $A\ne B$ such that $\sum A = \sum B$.

For example if $S_3 = \{1,2,4\}$ there are no such subsets but if $S_3= \{2,4, 6\}$ then there are.

I have tried for days to solve this with no luck but I am hoping it is the sort  of problem someone has solved before.

Comment: Do you intend for the subsets to be disjoint or just distinct?

Comment: @SammyBlack I mean just distinct.

Comment: I suspect getting an exact answer is hopeless. I also suspect that the probability of no such subsets is really really small for most $\ell$ and $n$. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @GregMartin  I would be happy to know its asymptotics but I do care how quickly it gets small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $n$ is even for simplicity. There are $n/2$ pairs of elements that add to $n+1$. A given pair of elements is present in $S_n$ with probability $1/4$. Therefore the probability that $S_n$ doesn't contain two such pairs is
$$
\bigg( \frac34 \bigg)^{n/2} + \frac n2 \frac14 \bigg( \frac34 \bigg)^{n/2-1},
$$
which is pretty darn small but already an upper bound for the probability you seek.

Comment: I am confused by your answer. Say $n=20$ and $\ell = 10$. Isn't the probability $1$? For which subset of size $10$ are there not two subsets that have the same sum?

Comment: The OP changed the question (to include $\ell$) after this answer was posted.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I hope the new phrasing makes more sense.