# Finding an upper bound for the probability of two random subsets $A,B$ of an $n$-element set $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ having equal sum of elements.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Fix $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $|S|=n$. Without the loss of generality, uniformly randomly pick two subsets $A, B$ of S. When picking $A$ or $B$, the probability of picking $x \in S$ is $1/n$ hence the uniformly random.

Could an upper bound on the probability that,

$$
\sum_{a \in A}a = \sum_{b\in B}b
$$

be calculated? E. g., $\{1, 4, 8\}$ has no such subsets. Whereas $\{1, 2, 3, 7\}$ does, namely $\{1,2,7\}$ and $\{3,7\}$.

I found similar questions but either the original set $S$ [is not general enough](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637724/783364) or [not fixed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3778386/783364) or [multisets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781996/783364) were allowed.

Edit: Including a helpful comment, I want,

$$
f(n) = \max_{S\subset\mathbb{N}:|S|=n} \mathbf{P}\left(\sum_{a \in A}a = \sum_{b\in B}b\right)
$$

where $A,B$ are identical independent uniform random variables on the power-set of $S$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you saying that  the sets $A,B$ are disjoint?  And are we to assume that $A\cup B=S$?  And are $A,B$ chosen uniformly in some sense?  And if so, what sense? And how is $S$ chosen in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, whatever it is that you are asking, it seems hard to get a handle on.  I'd expect the answer to  rapidly approach $0$ for large $n$ if that helps.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ do not have to be disjoint. See the edits. "And are we to assume that $A \cup B = S$," No. I tried to address the uniformly random part. When picking elements of $A$ or $B$, all elements of $S$ have an equal chance of getting picked.

Comment: This is all very vague.  Obviously the answer depends enormously on the set $S$..  I suggest you try a few examples.

Comment: The answer may not be obvious but I am not sure how is the question vague? Obviously if $S$ has special properties, e. g., $s_{i+1} > 2s_{i}$ then the probability is $0$ but it would help me if a general bound can be established.

Comment: I don't understand how the question is vague either. It seems perfectly clear to me, and I'm not sure how I would improve it.

Comment: My interpretation is: Suppose $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ is finite. Let $A,B$ be identical independent uniform random variables on the power-set $\mathcal{P}(S)$. The OP wants a good upper bound on the quantity $$f(n)=\max_{S\subset\mathbb{N}:|S|=n}P\left(\sum_{a\in A}a=\sum_{b\in B}b\right)$$

Comment: @C-RAM  That's not what the header asks.  That question asks for the probability that there exist two distinct subsets with the same sum.  I agree that it's possible the OP intended to ask your question, but it's all very vague.  For what it's worth, I'd expect that $\{1,\cdots, n\}$ or translates thereof has the highest probability of all sets of the same size that two "randomly" selected sets have the same sum.

Comment: If you want a real question, I'd ask that one:  Take the set $S=\{1, \cdots, n\}$ and select two distinct subsets $A,B$ uniformly at random from the set of pairs of distinct subsets.  What is the probability that they have the same sum?  Should be easily computable for small $n$ at least.

Comment: @lulu I don't see how that is not what the header asks, anyways, C-RAM's interpretation is correct. If you have a better way of wording the header, feel free to let me know.

Comment: You edited the header to change its meaning.  As I suggested, start with my special case.

Comment: @C-RAM  I'd advise leaving that sort of thing to the OP.  Up to you of course.

Comment: The OP _à la moi_ while not denying, still does not see how the original title was inconsistent with the body. By distinct sets I meant subsets that are not equal. I am glad C-RAM helped me better state the problem.

Comment: Wait, distinct and proper subsets? Oh no... it turns out I didn't understand your question fully. I would leave out that condition if I were you, since it overcomplicates the problem statement, and it's not hard to solve your problem if you know the solution to the case where $A,B$ aren't necessarily distinct and proper. I apologise for adding to the confusion. In any case, you might want to edit your question again because my restatements do not account for the fact that $A,B$ must be distinct and proper.

Comment: I took those out.

Comment: You want the probability that $\sum_i \sigma_i x_i = 0$, where the $x_i$ are the elements of $S$, and each $\sigma_i$ is a random variable equal to $0$ or $\pm 1$, depending on whether $x_i$ is in $A$, $B$, or both or neither.  If the $\sigma_i$ are mutually independent, seems like a CLT argument will apply.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, scribe?

Answer (score 2):

Let $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$.

$$g(n) =  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times \sum_{A,B} 1 \left(\sum_{a \in A} a = \sum_{b \in B} b \right)$$

Lets iterate over sum. Assume $\sum_{a \in A} a = \sum_{b \in B} b= N$
$$g(n) =  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times \sum_{N} \sum_{A,B} 1\left(\sum_{a \in A} a = N \right) \times 1 \left(\sum_{b \in B} b = N \right)$$
$$g(n) =  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times \sum_{N} \left( \sum_{A} 1\left(\sum_{a \in A} a = N \right) \right) \times \left( \sum_{B} 1 \left(\sum_{b \in B} b = N \right) \right)$$

$q_N$ is the number of subsets with sum equal to $N$.

$$g(n) =  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times \sum_{N} q_N \times q_N$$

$$g(n) =  \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times \sum_{N}  q_N^2 $$

$q_N$ is the number of partition of integer $N$ into distinct parts without repetition. Details are here (See Partions $Q$) https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/PartitionsQ/introductions/Partitions/ShowAll.html

Asymptotically, $$q_N = constant \times \frac{1}{N^{3/4}} e^{\pi \sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}} \left( 1+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\right)$$

Hence,  $$g(n) = constant \times \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \times n \times \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} e^{constant \times \sqrt{\frac{n}{3}}} \left( 1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^2$$

Find an accurate expression for $q_N$ and get the corresponding expression for $g(n)$ based on this. There must be lot of literature on $q_N$.

Comment: "$q_N$ is the number of subsets with sum equal to $N$." Number of subsets of what set? Presumably, number of subsets of $S$, which is an arbitrary set of $n$ natural numbers. "$q_N$  is the number of partition of integer $N$ into distinct parts without repetition." No, not unless $S=\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$. Aren't you silently making that assumption?

Comment: I assumed $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$. Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Although if you have an estimate of $q_N$ for a generic set $S$, you can still substitute in the expression i derived.

Answer (score 1):

It has been suggested in the comments that the maximum is attained when $S=\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$, so let's look at this case.
The number of pairs of subsets $\{A,B\}$ is $4^n$. [This count includes the cases where $A=B$, and the cases where we have one or more of $A=\{\}$, $B=\{\}$, $A=S$, $B=S$; the number of such cases is negligible, compared to $4^n$.]
The number of pairs with equal sum is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A047653 [although this interpretation of the sequence is not given there], which begins $1, 2, 4, 10, 26, 76, 236, 760,\dotsc$. E.g., for $n=3$, there are eight cases of $A=B$, and there's $\{A,B\}=\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$, making two more cases, total ten. [For small $n$, the cases $A=B$ dominate, but again their contribution is negligible for large $n$.]
No closed form formula is given at the oeis page, but an asymptotic expression is given:
$$
\sqrt{{3\over\pi}}n^{-3/2}4^n
$$
So, for large $n$, the probability of an equal sum is close to $(\sqrt{3/\pi})n^{-3/2}$, which goes to zero as $n\to\infty$.